# Network Console Tab in DevTools: Changing Request Name?

Tags: logging, frontend, devtools

I would like to improve the troubleshooting, and therefore would like to make it easier to find the requests I need. Current problem is that my requests are mostly only ids, so i have troubles finding the right one and it takes time. Therefore I would like to change the request Name, any way to do that?

I tried to set different header properties. Create custom ones, but I am unable to show them or to override the Name column.